# How do i Align image to left and text right with background included html?

Tags: php, html, css, styles

I am trying to align an image to the left and put text to the right, I have tried with

```
float:left
```

So I manage to align it but the text on the right starts at the foot of the photo and I want it to start from the beginning of the photo leaving some margin

Also in the image and text div, I have added a background for the image and the text, but it only follows the length of the text.

How i Align image to  left and text right with background included html?

Someone could help me with that.

```
<html>
 <head>
   <style>

.item-image {
  background-image: url("bkgd.jpg");
  background-color: #cccccc;
  float:left;
}

body {background-color: powderblue;}
h1   {color: blue;}
b    {color: red;}
</style> 
 </head>
 <body>

    <div class="item item-image">
<img src="<?= $_POST['imghide']; ?>" />Texto a la derecha alineado Texto a la derecha alineado Texto a la derecha alineado Texto a la derecha alineado Texto a la derecha alineado 
     </div>
<br clear="all">
</body>
</html>
```

Imagen [image: Image of result]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `float: left` on `.item-image`, you should be using it on the image itself. Margin will work on the image,

```
img{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

Also, to make the background size increase, add padding to the background like so:

```
.item-image{
  padding: 10px;
}
```

That will add space around the child elements of `.item-image` without increasing their size.